# Too few bytes written, Request & Response logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, httpcontext, kestrel-http-server

Currently working on an API. I'm trying to log the response body of a request made to the API. Everything I found until now did not work.

## Steps

- Log Request Data (passes all checks)
- Execute Request (passes)
- Log Response Data (Exception)

## Exception

The exception I am currently getting is

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
       Connection id "0HMA13HRIRMNB", Request id "0HMA13HRIRMNB:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
 System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (0 of 4959).
```

## Here is my current code

```
private async Task<RequestLog> LogResponse(HttpContext context, RequestLog log)
{
    Stream bodyStream = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = bodyStream;
    await _next(context);
    string text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    // System.Console.WriteLine(text);
    try
    {
        string requestPath = context.Request.Path.ToString();
        if (requestPath.StartsWith("/v") && !requestPath.Contains("swagger"))
        {
            log.ResponseBody = text;
            log.ResponseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
            log.TimestampEnd = DateTime.Now;
            return log;
        }
        return new RequestLog();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Exception handling...
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, any form of help would be very helpful! Thank you in advance

Comment: Once a stream has been read (by your `ReadToEndAsync`), it can't be read again (to send the response). You'll need to rewind or replace the response stream.

Comment: Alright, I'll try something out! thank you!

Comment: I tried changing the cursor position with `context.Response.Body.Position = 0;` and also tried to use `context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` in separate tests after I read the value. I still got the same error